# is "group by" capability present in JXLS 2.x version?

Tags: jxls

in JXLS 1.x version, 
you can group the data in a collection by using group by attribute inside jx:forEach tag.

is this capability present in JXLS 2.x version?
it's not working for me ...

i have tried sth like this as a comment in excel
**jx:each(items="employees" lastCell="N4" groupBy="name")**

Answer (score 0):

The current version jxls-2.2.9 does not have a built-in support for the *groupBy* attribute. 
So you can raise an improvement request or implement it yourself by extending Each-command.